# Icons will not format in the navigation menu bar

Tags: html, css, formatting, icons, navigationbar

I am having an issue where the Facebook icon and the Instagram icon is not formatted in the navigation menu bar, it is just below it and won't go inside the bar. I need the icons to be to the right of the navigation bar with some space between the header and the icon, but they are lined up in the center together.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lunation Boards</title>
    <link rel = "icon" href="LogoBlack.PNG" type="image/SVG">
</head>
<style>
    body {margin:0;}
    .Header {
        z-index: 100;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
        height: 70px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        .Header.responsive {position: relative;}
        .Header.responsive li.icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 960px){
    .Header {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 86px;
        height: 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    }
    .headerLogo{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: small;
        font-style: italic;
        font-family: Verdana;
        color: white;
    }

</style>
<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/LunationBoards/Home.html" ><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center;">Lunation Boards</h1></a>
        <style>
            a{text-decoration: none}
        </style>
    </a>
    <a class = "Facebook" style = "padding-left: 1000px;">
        <img src = "facebook-3-xxl.png">
    </a>
    <a class = "Instagram" style = "padding-left: 30px">
        <img src = "instagram-32.png">
    </a>
</div>
</body>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean put the styles between the head section, like this

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lunation Boards</title>
    <link rel = "icon" href="LogoBlack.PNG" type="image/SVG">
<style>
    body {margin:0;}
    .Header {
        z-index: 100;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
        height: 70px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        .Header.responsive {position: relative;}
        .Header.responsive li.icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 960px){
    .Header {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 86px;
        height: 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    }
    .headerLogo{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: small;
        font-style: italic;
        font-family: Verdana;
        color: white;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your style has to be in the `<head>` section.

Comment: It's inside the <div class = "header"> which incorporates the the navigation menu bar in the styles tag so both icons should be inside the menu bar. But it isn't.